# nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java and I want to know what is wrong with this code, it is giving me an error saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random
>
> at Random.main(Random.java:8)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.out.println(rnd.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- You defined your own class `Random`; 2- You didn't use the `java.util.Random` class

Answer (score 4):

Your `Random` class hides `java.util.Random`. Rename your class.

`Random rnd = new Random();` creates an instance of your class instead of `java.util.Random`, and your class has no `nextInt` method.

Answer (score 2):

When Java sees a declaration of an object, what class is referred to depends on how the object is declared.

- If the name of the class is not fully qualified, then java will look first in the package the class is in, and then search the classes and packages in import statements to try to find the appropriate class.
- If the name of the class in the declaration is fully qualified, then the fully qualified class will be used, i.e. you are telling the compiler exactly which class of object you want your object to be.

In your case, you have your own class called Random, which is importing `java.util.Random`. However, because the class name is not fully qualified at the declaration time, the class `Random` in the current package takes precedence, which means the import of `java.util.Random` in your file is effectively ignored.

Some Options:

- Rename your class
- Use fully qualified class name when you wish to refer to java.util.Random

e.g.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Random {

public static void main(String[] args){

    java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();

    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt(100));

  }
}
```

In this instance, using the fully qualified name disambiguates the class you wish to reference and explicitly tells Java which version to use.

If this is for learning then a class with the same name might be fine, however, for code which needs to be maintained by others in the long term, you may want to reconsider your naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this cause a conflict between java.util.Random and your own Random class. I think in the line you have write `Random rnd = new Random();` It creates an object from your own Random class. It;s better to rename your class to `CustomizeRandom` or sth like this

Answer (score 0):

As [@Eran already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655500/1803692), you just used `Random` class (user defined) but you need to use the `java.util.Random` class.

Here is a working example that might help you:

```
import java.util.Random;
class RandomNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rdm= new Random();
        int c=100;
        System.out.println("no is "+rdm.nextInt(c));
    }
}
```

It generates a number between 0 and 100 and you can also use other methods of the `Random` class.

Edited: @vogel & @trengot Thanks for editing this answer, from next time i will answer in better formal language. (y)